# How to convert a .vpp file to pdf file

Tags: uml

I have done a class and sequence diagram i Visual Paradigm, file saved as .vpp file extension. Is there a free tool online that can convert a visual paradigm .vpp file to pdf?
Regards
Dan

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to convert it somewhere else as Visual Paradigm provides this functionality.

In Project overview select "Export as Image..." and then select "PDF files"

Comment: Thanks peter. I'm using the Visual paradigm Community edition, and under diagram overview, i do not see where to select  'Export as Image'. Could it be on Another version?

Comment: @DanA Yeah I meant overview of diagrams (= project overview). Also please mark the question as answered.